# Error while receiving image from postman to python Flask API: 400 Bad request

Tags: image, api, flask, request, postman

I have been trying to deploy a python predictive model using flask API however I am not able to receive the image request. It works fine when I test it using text but I think I am missing something when it comes to dealing with Images. I have uploaded the image to postman using the form-data and set the key to type 'file' and name 'image'.

This is the error on postman I am getting:

werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this
server could not understand.
KeyError: 'file'

In my flask code, I am using this line of code to receive the request:

imagefile = request.files['image']

Please help me figure this out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before. You can try to add this to your code:

```
from flask import Flask

#python3 -m pip install flask-cors
#installation command
from flask_cors import CORS

#You can specify the app variable's name CORS(your_app)
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/")
def helloWorld():
  return "Hello, cross-origin-world!"
```

Full Documentation:https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Also if you are trying to use HTTPS just change it to HTTP.